# Be a little less rigid about new users

Tags: discussion, upvotes, privileges

This is not a question, rather a request. If I have posted it in the wrong place, I wouldn't mind the correction. I want to say that you guys should allow guys new to this community to at least be able to up-vote a solution which has helped them out. I have plenty of questions I would want to show have helped, and it would have been awesome to just be able to up-vote it without having to go through more stages to get the capability to do so.

Comment: No, we can't.  They do all kinds of really nonconstructive stuff that takes lots and lots of work to clean up.  Like posting questions in the completely wrong place.

Comment: Irony at its finest..

Answer (score 23):

Voting restrictions are there for a reason. If anyone could upvote anything it would be a lot easier for people to create sock puppet accounts to upvote their own posts. Right now this is a real problem that moderators have to deal with, but I'm sure it would be far worse if voting restrictions weren't in place.

If you really want to thank people who have helped you, do as they do and give back by answering a few questions. Before you know it you'll have enough reputation to unlock voting privileges.